# How can I  remove a language which I don't know where was set?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

In the **bin/debug** folder of the project with **Culture Info** *activated*, after each build, nearby the **ru-RU** folder a folder with the name **ar-BH** appears which stores the resources for some controls (an **dll** file).

I think that accidentally was set this language sometime, and i don't know were those controls could be located.

Is it a possibility to find, or how to remove the not required languages?

Comment: do you have resource files in your app? Do you reference a DLL that have satellite assemblies?

Comment: yes Steve, there are a resource file resource.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a disassembler tool to find where was set the ar-BH language, and after that I have removed the resource file from Visual Studio Solution Explorer.